# Passing in a Parameter in Google Spreadsheet Script from Script Assignment

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to make my own button in a Google Spreadsheet, and I have a script called incrementContents that takes in a parameter (a cell location, eg 'B3') and increments that location by one.

My question is this- is there a way to pass in a parameter to this function via the same text box where I assign the script to the button (right click -> assign script)? Something like;

incrementContents('B3')
or
incrementContents, B3

I'm not sure of the syntax, and knowing how to do this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You could do a couple of things -

1. Ask the user for the input using [`Browser.inputBox`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser#inputBox%28String%29)
2. Read cell's value from the script itself (if the cell reference is always constant) using an example like [`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1")`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange%28String%29)

Comment: Pointless though. If they have to select the cell, it is completely fragile and useless. If they have to do that, what is the point of the button? It is too easy to wreck the sheet by clicking the button without picking the perfect range first. Google spreadsheet scripting is a joke IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

The way I am trying to work around this problem is by having the user edit a cell instead of adding a button to the cell. (Eg. typing "ok" in the cell.) This triggers the onEdit() function or a custom function that is passed the event parameter that can be used to get data from the sheet relative to the cell where the "ok" was entered.